# Work shift recognition based on date and time

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, loops

I have a schedule of work shifts `A, B, C, D` where each shift works from `7:15 to 7:14`
for example:

```
shift A from 7:15 to 19:14
shift C from 19:15 to 7:14
shift D from 7:15 to 19:14
shift B from 19:15 to 7:14
```

The schedule is in this way : `C, A, C, A, D, B, D, B, A, C, A, C, B, D, B, D`
and then the loop will restart.

I want to create a program that gives me wish shift is working on a specific date and time
for example `7/14/2016` at 12 will give me `A`.

Any idea how to do it ?

Comment: A and D, C and B are the same - that simplifies your schedule somewhat

Comment: no not the same, a different shift each which means i have 4 shifts

Comment: Why is there a C right after a B? Does that mean there's a empty shift in between the two?

Comment: Where do you state which shift works on what day? You have only given times of the shifts but as stated before A and D, and C and B are the same times. Need more information to go by.

Comment: the loop starts with C that is the morning shift and A the night shift for two days. Then D will be the morning shift and B the night shift for the next two days. Then A will be the morning shift and C the night shift for the next two days. Then B will be the morning shift and D the night shift for the next two days. and the loop will restart this will give a schedule that is : C A C A D B D B A C A C B D B D

Comment: What day of the week (or date in time) does the first shift start from? Without that information you can't calculate the result

Comment: Isnt shift C the night shift and shift A be the day shift? So even the shifts that you've assigned times to change?

Comment: If this is to assign people to work shifts, there are better ways to do it

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to write a T-SQL expression that will evaluate to what you're looking for.

```
case dateadd(minute, @baseTime, @myTime) / (1440 * 8) % 2
    when 0
        case dateadd(minute, @baseTime, @myTime) / (1440 * 4) % 2
            when 0 then
                case dateadd(minute, @baseTime, @myTime) / (1440 * 4) / 720 % 2
                    when 0 then 'C' when 1 then 'A' end
        when 1 then
            case dateadd(minute, @baseTime, @myTime) / (1440 * 4) / 720 % 2
                when 0 then 'D' when 1 then 'B' end
    when 1
        case dateadd(minute, @baseTime, @myTime) / (1440 * 4) % 2
            when 0 then
                case dateadd(minute, @baseTime, @myTime) / (1440 * 4) / 720 % 2
                    when 0 then 'A' when 1 then 'C' end
        when 1 then
            case dateadd(minute, @baseTime, @myTime) / (1440 * 4) / 720 % 2
                when 0 then 'B' when 1 then 'D' end
end
```

You could make this work with negative numbers but it would probably be easier to pick a `@baseTime` that's far enough into the past that you don't have to worry about it. Obviously your cycle repeats every 16 days and you can just logically extend it backward in time as far as necessary for the purposes of this calculation. If you need this in VB.Net it is straightforward to translate. Just make sure to use integer division (`\`) instead of "regular" division (`/`).

I started the little formula above before I realized that the pairs of shifts were swapped in the latter half. Although it was easy to extend it has probably gotten a little long to read easily. Thankfully you can describe any kind of scheduling by taking the number of minutes and using the ranges of values for each of the shifts. This is very clear and easy to modify.

```
declare @min int = datediff(minute, @baseTime, @myTime) % (1440 * 8)
select case
    when @min between     0 and   719 then 'A'
    when @min between   720 and  1439 then 'C'
    ...
    when @min between 10080 and 11519 then 'D'
end
```

Mostly for fun, a compact way of writing this pattern is also possible using the formula below and the "shift number" within the sixteen cycles starting at zero and counting to fifteen. As output let 1 correspond with A, 2 with B, 3 with C, 4 with D.

```
1 + 2 * ((shiftNumber + shiftNumber / 8 % 2 + 1) % 2) + (shiftNumber / 4 % 2)
```

And here's some T-SQL code to see that the pattern is correct:

```
create table T (n int );
insert into T (n) values (0), (1),  (2),  (3),  (4),  (5),  (6),  (7),
                         (8), (9), (10), (11), (12), (13), (14), (15);

select
    n + 1 as num,
    substring('ABCD', 1 + 2 * ((n + n / 8 % 2) % 2) + (n / 4 % 2), 1) as shift
from T order by n;
```

http://rextester.com/HCHZG96643

In code you can easily calculate the shift number to use in place of `n`.

```
declare @shiftNumber int = datediff(minute, @baseTime, @myTime) / 720 % 16;
```

Answer (score -3):

Before going into the solution for the problem I want to try to clarify the confusion about what was being communicated. If we take your schedule and replace the letters with timeframes we get

```
C, A, C, A
19:15 to 7:14, 7:15 to 19:14, 19:15 to 7:14, 7:15 to 19:14,
```

This sequence seems logical but then you shift to

```
D, B, D, B, A, C, A, C,
7:15 to 19:14, 19:15 to 7:14, 7:15 to 19:14, 19:15 to 7:14, 7:15 to 19:14, 19:15 to 7:14, 7:15 to 19:14, 19:15 to 7:14,
```

By itself this sequence is fine but the question arises when you combine the two sequences. At the point of combination you get

```
C, A, D, B
19:15 to 7:14, 7:15 to 19:14, 7:15 to 19:14, 19:15 to 7:14,
```

And again this inconsistency seems to occur when go from

```
A, C, B, D
7:15 to 19:14, 19:15 to 7:14, 19:15 to 7:14, 7:15 to 19:14,
```

Still in your defense perhaps there is a reason for this seeming inconsistency where an entire shift seems to get skipped.

Second you say you have 4 shifts and if that were completely true then you could have a sequence of C, B, C, B and have that be completely valid, however I am guessing that is not the case and you actually only have 2 shifts but you also have perhaps 2 crews or something to that affect and I also noticed they seemed to be paired shifts so your first table might be better displayed as:

```
Shift A1 from 7:15 to 19:14
Shift A2 from 19:15 to 7:14
Shift B1 from 7:15 to 19:14
Shift B2 from 19:15 to 7:14
```

This still does not account for the seemingly missing Shifts but it would help clarify for some what you are striving for.

Still again in your defense neither of these makes any difference since we are really only working on what shift is working on what day using the following pattern:

C, A, C, A, D, B, D, B, A, C, A, C, B, D, B, D

Of course Matt Wilko did denote one of the parameters to the function when he said that you will need to supply the starting day of that first shift (19:15 to 7:14 or C).

Of course none of this restricts one from creating a function for this provided the caveats needed are clearly defined for the end developer as follows:

Written using C# syntax and functionalities as I code faster in C# but being also a VBA programmer I know it can be fairly easily translated into VBA

```
/*
Parameters:  SeqStartDate (DateTime) - The date that the beginning of the schedule sequence falls upon (aka the date that the first C of C, A, C, A falls on) 
             RequstPeriod (DateTime) - The specific period you are wanting the schedule for.

Returns:     Shift (int) - A numeric representation of the specific shift being worked, for the requested time period
                           (0 = No Shift, 1 = Shift A, 2 = Shift C, 3 = Shift D, 4 = Shift B)

                  Error: - If an error occurs it will return a negative number corresponding to the error
                           However for demonstration purposes it will for now just return -1

Assumptions: Since there are missing shifts a zero has been added to account for these
             That only future shift schedules are desired
             RequstPeriod must occur at least a day after the SeqStartDate
             RequstPeriod must occur at least a day after this program is being run

Modification Note: This could be made more robust and eliminate some of the assumptions but
                   I think what is here should give the basic concept and I will leave the
                   modifying to fit the developers specific needs to the developer
*/
public int GetShift(SeqStartDate as DateTime, RequstPeriod as DateTime)
{
    // First Validate Inputs

    // Today’s Date 1 Second past Midnight
    TodayIs = ((DateTime.Now()).Date).AddTicks(1);

    TimeSpan SeqTSpan = RequstPeriod.Subtract(SeqStartDate)
    if (SeqTSpan.Minutes < 1440)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    TimeSpan TodayTSpan = RequstPeriod.Subtract(TodayIs)
    if (TodayTSpan.Minutes < 1440)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    long SchdMins = 0;
    long SeqShftr = 0;
    int SchdIndx = 0;

    // A Zero represents a missing shift within the continuous schedule sequence
    int ShftSchedSeq[] = {1,2,1,0,3,4,3,4,1,2,1,2,0,4,3,4,3,2};
    long ShftSeqStartMins[] = {57,1155,1497,2595,2937,4035,4377,5475,5817,6915,7257,8355,5697,9795,10137,11235,11577,12675}
    const long FirstStartTimeMin = 57;
    const int IndxCnt = 18;  // Note C# is a 0 based array thus the adjustment later

    // The following assumes Integer division truncates and gives a number from 1 to 8 in SeqShftr
    TimeSpan SeqShftrTSpan = TodayIs.Subtract((SeqStartDate.Date).AddTicks(1))

    // Note  %  means Modulo to ease translation
    SeqShftr = ((((SeqShftrTSpan.Minutes) / 1440) % 9) * 2);

    SchdMins = SeqTSpan.Minutes % 12960

    // Is the SchdMins less than smallest value in Shift Schedule Array?
    if (SchdMins < FirstStartTimeMin)
    {
       // If yes then it is part of the previous sequence shift which would be the last sequence shift
       ShftIndx = IndxCnt - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        // For Loop Counts Down from MaxIndx-1 to 0
        for (int Indx = (IndxCnt-1); Indx => 0; Indx—-)
        {
            if (ShftSeqStartMins[Indx] <= SchdMins)
            {
                ShftIndx = Indx;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    ShftIndx = (ShftIndx + SeqShftr);
    if (ShftIndx > (IndxCnt - 1))
    {
        ShftIndx = ShftIndx - (IndxCnt - 1);
    }

    return ShftSchedSeq[ShftIndx];    
}
```

Final Note:  Having looked at one of your comments I find that you appear to be a bit confused — Still to adjust the above program all you need to do is adjust the values in the ScheduleSequence Array (and perhaps the ShftSeqStartMins array) to what they should be once you figure out how you want that to be.  As a Morning Shift cannot also be a Night Shift and vice-versa as you have stated in the comment that I am referring to.